# Crash delete [ ] initialized char string

Tags: c++, string, initialization

After having fixed bugs coming from uninitialized pointers. an old bug still stand, it crashes in `stringclass::alloc()` if I delete mystring though we can handle or display it just before. It has been initialized so what happened this time?

```
void stringclass::alloc(long newsize)
{     
   if(memsize < newsize)
   {
       cout << "checkpoint 1\n";
       if(mystring) delete [] mystring;
       cout << "checkpoint 2\n";
       memsize = newsize;
       mystring = new char[memsize];
       mystring[0] = 0;
       length = 0;
    }
}
```

**Full code :**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#define DEFAULT_BREAKPOINT -1
#define DEFAULT_STARTPOINT -1

class stringclass
{
   protected :

      inline bool success()   { failbit = false;  return true; }
      inline bool fail()      { failbit = true; return false; }

   public :

      bool failbit;

      long memsize;
      long length;
      char * mystring;

      bool ins(const char * str, long startpoint, long breakpoint);


      inline long get_length()       { if(mystring) length = strlen(mystring); return length;}
      inline long get_memsize() const { return memsize; }

      void reset();
      void alloc(long newsize);

      void copy(const stringclass & other);
      stringclass();
      stringclass(const char str[]);
      stringclass(const stringclass & other);
      ~stringclass();

      friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, stringclass & sc){out << sc.mystring; return out;}

};

void stringclass::copy(const stringclass & other)
{
   if(other.mystring == NULL)
   {
      reset();
      return;
   }

   alloc(other.memsize);
   strcpy(mystring, other.mystring);
   length = other.length;
}

stringclass::stringclass()
   : mystring(NULL), memsize(0), length(0)
{
}

stringclass::stringclass(const char str[])
   : mystring(NULL), memsize(0), length(0)
{
   if(str != NULL)
   {
      alloc(strlen(str) + 1);
      strcpy(mystring, str);
      length = strlen(mystring);
   }
}

stringclass::stringclass(const stringclass & other) 
   : mystring(NULL), memsize(0), length(0)
{
   copy(other);
}

stringclass::~stringclass()
{
   delete [] mystring;
}

void stringclass::reset()
{
   if(mystring) delete [] mystring;
   mystring = NULL;
   length = 0;
   memsize = 0;
}

void stringclass::alloc(long newsize)
{     
   if(memsize < newsize)
   {
       cout << "checkpoint 1\n";
       if(mystring) delete [] mystring;
       cout << "checkpoint 2\n";
       memsize = newsize;
       mystring = new char[memsize];
       mystring[0] = 0;
       length = 0;
    }
}

bool stringclass::ins(const char * str, long startpoint = DEFAULT_STARTPOINT, long breakpoint = DEFAULT_BREAKPOINT)
{
   if(startpoint == DEFAULT_STARTPOINT) startpoint = 0;
   if(breakpoint == DEFAULT_BREAKPOINT) breakpoint = startpoint;

   if(breakpoint > length || breakpoint - startpoint < 0) return fail();
   if(str == NULL) return fail();

   long str_length = strlen(str);
   long temp_size = 0;
   bool to_resize = false;

   if(length + str_length + 1 - (breakpoint - startpoint) > memsize)
   {
      temp_size = (length + str_length + 1 - (breakpoint - startpoint));
      to_resize = true;
   }
   else temp_size = memsize;

   char * temp = new char[temp_size];

   long temp_i = 0;

   if(mystring) for(; temp_i < startpoint; temp_i++) temp[temp_i] = mystring[temp_i];
   for(long str_i = 0; str_i < str_length; str_i++, temp_i++) temp[temp_i] = str[str_i];
   if(mystring) for(long buf_i = breakpoint; buf_i < memsize; buf_i++, temp_i++)temp[temp_i] = mystring[buf_i];

   temp[temp_i] = 0;

   if(to_resize) alloc(temp_size); //empty

   for(long buf_i = 0; buf_i < memsize; buf_i++) mystring[buf_i] = temp[buf_i];

   if(temp) delete [] temp;
   length = strlen(mystring);

   return success();
}


int main()
{

      stringclass str = "Hello";

      str.ins("rld", str.get_length());
      cout << str << endl;

      str.ins(" the wo", 5);
      cout << str << endl;

      system("PAUSE");
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: This actually runs - http://ideone.com/60eXuI

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: likely it is UB, so it can run for you and crash for others.

Answer (score 2):

You're overflowing a buffer.

This

```
char * temp = new char[temp_size];
```

should be

```
char * temp = new char[temp_size+1];
```

Also your class has no assignment operator, so assigning it will do a shallow copy and result in a double delete.

Comment: the +1 is already taken into account with memsize and temp_size : temp_size = length + str_length + 1 - (breakpoint - startpoint)
temp_size = memsize;

Comment: `valgrind` says `temp[temp_i] = 0;` writes past the end of the allocated array. `valgrind` does not lie. Either the buffer is too small or you increment `temp_i` too many times.

Comment: yes okay it comes from this point temp[temp_i] = 0; should be if(temp_i - 1 >= 0) temp[temp_i - 1] = 0; Thank you.

Comment: @nomatch - The missing assignment operator will also be important, as soon as you do something more with the string.

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely I took the operator overloads off to shrink the code. But why and how would no assignment operator for my class result in a double delete?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be writing your own string class if you need to ask that. Consider `stringclass s1("hello"); stringclass s2("goodbye"); s2=s1;` -- that code has a memory leak _and_ a double delete.